# The proper use of smoke grenades - Men of War Assault Squad

Tags: men-of-war

I have a question about how to use smoke grenades. Most infantry seem to have them, and they are the obvious solution for attacking an strong enemy position (i.e. trench, field gun, tank).

I seem to be having issues on higher difficulty skirmish against the AI with the position of my smoke screens. I'm not sure if they are meant to be on top of the position you are attacking, or between your current position and where the enemy is located. It seems like either method leads to my infantry getting torn apart.

**What is the most effective method to deploy a smoke screen, and how are units affected by them?**

Answer (score 2):

A couple of things to note about the smoke grenade

1. It only obstructs line of sight(LOS), if your units catch enough attention inside the smoke(shooting, running near to the edge of the smoke screen) they'll still be spotted and they'll be as good as not in cover.
2. It takes time to deploy. At the instant the smoke grenade detonate, there is almost no effect on the LOS, wait a few seconds for the cloud to fully form and block off the unit's vision before moving out from your current cover.

There are two ways to use a smoke grenade, either to bring units into an advantageous position for a fight or to directly bring units into your enemies, the former is easier.

**Smoking for Position**

If there is only one very powerful gun or weapon you are concerned with, throw the smoke as close to the gun as possible in-between the gun and the open area you need to clear before entering cover - if you can throw the smoke directly on the gun just throw a normal grenade instead, that'll do a better job.

Otherwise if there is an entire line of defence that you need to overcome, throw the smoke in the open area between your units and the cover you will be fighting in, you might need to throw multiple or throw more as you proceed until you enter cover.

Once you are in cover your unit should also be unable to see the enemies otherwise you'd be under fire before reaching the cover. You can either wait for the smoke to clear before engaging in a shootout, or you could get another unit to a position further away that is not obstructed by the smoke and spot for your units in position to shoot(manual command is required as that unit have no LOS of it's target).

**Smoking for Attack**

For directly assaulting a position, one smoke is never enough. Depending on how far the defensive line of your enemy is stretched, you might need to throw that first as close to yourself as required to crawl out of the current position. Subsequently, throw each smoke in front of the current cloud you are in to chain into a path for your units to approach the defence. If the opponent is a human player instead of AI, throw even more to confuse them, that their manual firing into the smoke will hit less of your units.

Once close enough to the defence, use explosives to clear it out before taking up position in that cover(might need to use sandbags to make some ).

Answer (score 0):

I give one guy five or six smokes and a few AT grenades or dynamite. Then have them make a line of smoke to the target and crawl through it until they're in range. Normal grenades will work on trenches but make sure you cook them first.